# Bluetooth low energy: detect what system is running on central

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

is there a way for a peripheral to determine to what central it is connected to?

Suppose i have a peripheral device that can connect to a PC, a Smartphone, or a smart TV, etc. The peripheral is an arduino based system, therefore has got some intelligence and i want it to behave in different ways according to what the central it is connected to is. What would be the best way to understand what the central is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine the connected central device type, the way you asked. One way to do is program your arduino to act differently as per the BD_ADDR addresses of the central device. But in this case, you need to know the addresses of all your central devices, and it works only with known set of devices. Also some central devices may not use public BD_ADDR addresses. For example Apple devices use random addresses. In this case you don't know the real BD_ADDR address, until your device pairs with central device. You can't rely on their names because Bluetooth device names can be changed.